# Sqlite DataAdapter isn't updating when called

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have to write identical tables to two different Sqlite database. The tables rewrite existing data and ids, so I currently just delete the entire table and rewrite. Depending on the order that I write to the db, the C# `SQLiteCommandBuilder` does not update the second db called.

If I call `Db_A` before `Db_B`, then `A` gets written and `B` gets deleted and vice versa. Can anyone tell me why the second table enters the code to get deleted, but the Sqlite adapter never updates the second table? It doesn't throw an error either.

```
public static bool WriteDt_Name(DataTable dt)
{
    using (connA = GetDbAConn())
    {
        SaveDataTable(connA, dt);
    }
    using (connB = GetDbBConn())
    {
        SaveDataTable(connB, dt);
    }
    return true;
}

public static void SaveDataTable(SQLiteConnection conn, DataTable dt)
{
    string table = dt.TableName;
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM {0}", table);
    int val = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", table);

    using (var adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        using (SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter))
        {
            adapter.Update(dt);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}

public static SQLiteConnection GetDbAConn()
{
    string base_dir = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    string path = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(base_dir).ToString()).ToString()).ToString()).ToString()).ToString();
    path = path + "\\db\\DbA.sqlite;";
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + path + "Version=3;");
    return conn;
}
```

I have tried splitting `SaveDataTable` into a `SaveDt_A` and `SaveDt_B` and calling it that way. I still get the same result.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, why do you explicitly call `Dispose()` in some of your `using` statements?

Comment: I didn't originally and shouldn't be included in this sample. Just trying anything at this point.

Comment: Okay, so I have figured out that it has something to do with the methods being within a static class. I'm not sure why this is an issue though.

Comment: You close the connection but then never re-open it.  That's an odd pattern.  Just use another using-block on the connection in your method to open it and automatically close it.  Let the connection pool do it's work.

Comment: I actually do reopen it with 'connB = GetDbBConn()'. That line opens a new connection to another Db at a different location.